# How to format and save console output to file in Java?

Tags: java, file, console, format, output

*Background: Hello! First of all, please have in mind that I'm fairly new to Java, thus, forgive me if I have something wrong. I have been trying to format my console and save its output to a text file for 2 days now. Here's my code so far:*

I'm trying to set the format of the console to

> [12/20/2017 23:55:30] program(message here)

and I'm doing it like this:

```
public class Format {
    private static final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    PrintStream console = new PrintStream(System.out) {

        public void println(String x) {
            Date date = new Date();
            super.println("[" + sdf.format(date) + "] " + "program(" + x + ")");
        }
    };
```

Along with this:

```
    public void progStream() throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.setOut(console);
        System.out.println("This is a test.");
    }
```

Up to here it works just fine and I can see all the system outputs show up on the eclipse's console with the correct format. However, when I try to save it a text file it saves only the message. Without the format.

```
    public void progStream() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File log = new File("log" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(log);
        PrintStream console = new PrintStream(fos);
        System.setOut(console);
        System.out.println("This is a test.");
    }
```

I have tried replacing `System.out.println("message");` with `console.print("message");` but I get the same issue. Unfortunately, I have run out of tutorials and forums to look out and I still can't find a solution to this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use a logging API, there's one built in to the core API or you could use something `Log4j`

Comment: Can you try posting a simple entire code as partial codes are quite confusing to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you never use the Format class you created to prepend your output with the date. You should have created an instance of this class and call the method `println()` of the `console` field of the newly created instance. Below is your code, slightly modified, that I suppose does what you want:

```
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;
  import java.io.PrintStream;
  import java.text.DateFormat;
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.Date;

  public class So_47900381 {

    static public class Format {
      private static final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
      PrintStream console = new PrintStream(System.out) {;
        public void println(String x) {
          Date date = new Date();
          super.println("[" + sdf.format(date) + "] " + "program(" + x + ")");
        }
      };
    }

    public static void progStream() throws FileNotFoundException {
      File log = new File("log" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt");
      PrintStream console = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(log));
      System.out.println("Writing to " + log.getPath());
      System.setOut(console);
      Format fmt = new Format();
      fmt.console.println("This is a test.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
       progStream();
      } catch (Exception x) { x.printStackTrace(); }
    }

  }
```

But I think there's no need to have a separate field, that is a descendant of the `PrintStream` and used to print to, inside the `Format` class. The class itself could descend from the `PrintStream` as well. Look at the code below:

```
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.io.PrintStream;
  import java.text.DateFormat;
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.Date;

  public class So_47900381_1{

    static public class Format extends PrintStream {
      private static final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

      public Format(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(file);
        System.setOut(this);
      }

      public void println(String x) {
        Date date = new Date();
        super.println("[" + sdf.format(date) + "] " + "program(" + x + ")");
      }
    }

    public static void progStream() throws FileNotFoundException {
      File log = new File("log" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt");
      System.out.println("Writing to " + log.getPath());
      Format fmt = new Format(log);          // redirects the output to the file
      System.out.println("This is a test."); // now it's written to the file 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        progStream();
      } catch (Exception x) { x.printStackTrace(); }
    }

  }
```

And yes, look at the `log4j` and/or google for `java logging`.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. I have about a week or two working with Java so this is all new to me. Your answer is very much appreciated.

Comment: @DavidMorales :) Then mark it as accepted :) And note that I have changed it a little - `System.out.println("This is a test.")` in the latter snippet

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you want to achieve:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class HelloWorld {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    PrintStream console = new PrintStream(System.out);
    PrintStream file = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("log" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt")));  

    Format format = new Format();

    // console
    format.print("bla", console);

    // file
    format.print("bla", file);  
  }
}

public class Format {

  private static final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

  public void print(String x, PrintStream stream) {
     Date date = new Date();
     stream.println("[" + sdf.format(date) + "] " + "program(" + x + ")");
  }

}
```

PS.: If you really want to log things, I recommend you to consider a logging framework like log4j.

PS. 2: `System.setOut(stream)` does NOT seem a good idea as your [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) will be redirected to the file.

I hope my answer helps you :)

Comment: Thank you! It worked. The best part is that I actually understood what I was doing wrong. I will read about logging frameworks, thank you for the reference!

Comment: Nice I could help :)